# How to use helper functions to create a stored procedure that updates two fields mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, dml

So I have a few tables on mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salarygrade` (
  `GRADE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `HOURLYRATE` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GRADE`));
```

===========================================================================

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staffongrade` (
  `STAFFNO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `GRADE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINISHDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `STAFFONGRADE_FK` (`STAFFNO` ASC),
  INDEX `STAFFONGRADE2_FK` (`GRADE` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`GRADE`, `STAFFNO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STAFFONG_STAFFONGR_SALARYGR`
  FOREIGN KEY (`GRADE`)
  REFERENCES `salarygrade` (`GRADE`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STAFFONG_STAFFONGR_STAFF`
  FOREIGN KEY (`STAFFNO`)
  REFERENCES `staff` (`STAFFNO`));
```

===========================================================================

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campaign` (
  `CAMPAIGN_NO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `TITLE` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `THEME` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGNSTARTDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTIMATEDCOST` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTUALCOST` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CAMPAIGN_NO`),
  INDEX `OWNS_FK` (`CUSTOMER_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAMPAIGN_OWNS_CUSTOMER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `customer` (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT);
```

===========================================================================

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workson` (
  `STAFFNO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_NO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `WDATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `HOUR` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`STAFFNO`, `CAMPAIGN_NO`, `WDATE`),
  INDEX `WORKSON_FK` (`STAFFNO` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_WORKSON_WORKSON2_CAMPAIGN_idx` (`CAMPAIGN_NO` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_WORKSON_WORKSON2_CAMPAIGN`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CAMPAIGN_NO`)
    REFERENCES `campaign` (`CAMPAIGN_NO`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_WORKSON_WORKSON_STAFF`
    FOREIGN KEY (`STAFFNO`)
    REFERENCES `staff` (`STAFFNO`));
```

And I want to create a stored procedure called `sp_finish_campaign (in c_title varchar(30))` that takes a title of a campaign and finishes the campaign by updating the `CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE` to the current date and `ACTUALCOST` to the cost of the campaign, which is calculated from the number of hours different staff put into it on different dates, and the salary grade (this changes based on staffID and the timeframe based on the `STARTDATE` and `FINISHDATE` of the `staffongrade` table.

To calculate the `ACTUALCOST`, I created a helper function:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION rate_on_date(staff_id int, given_date date)
    RETURNS int
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE salaryGrade int;
    SET salaryGrade = (select grade from staffongrade
    where staffno = staff_id AND (given_date BETWEEN STARTDATE AND FINISHDATE));
RETURN salaryGrade;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Which returns the pay `grade` based on the `staff_id` and `given_date` parameters I give it:

`select rate_on_date(1, "2018-02-02") as Grade_On_Date;`

[image: gradetable]

For the parameters of this I assume I would have to get it from the `workson` table which looks like this:

[image: workson]

I have tried using a select statement to get the paygrade:

`select hourlyrate as 'grade' from salarygrade
where rate_on_date(1, "2018-02-02") = grade;`

[image: pay]

To calculate `ACTUALCOST` I assume I would have to do a calculation by multiplying `HOUR` column with the grade costs, and use the `WDATE` and `STAFFNO` columns in the `workson` table as parameters for my stored procedure that will calculate and update the `CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE` and `ACTUALCOST` of the campaign by inputting the campaign title into it. 
But how would I go about doing this?

I'm just confused as to how to go about creating this procedure, and also confused about how to properly use these helper functions in my stored procedure. 
I feel like this question is quite long but I don't really know what to ask or what direction I should take to solve this problem.

Comment: staffongrade table.? I don't see (but I do see two salarygrade)

Comment: Sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a function. mysql can do multi-table updates (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) in your case it could look like this

```
update  campaign c
join 
(select c.campaign_no,
         sum(hour * hourlyrate) cost
from campaign c
join workson  w on w.campaign_no = c.campaign_no
join staffongrade s on s .staffno = w.staffno and w.wdate between s.startdate and s.finishdate
join salarygrade g on g.grade = s.grade
group by c.campaign_no
) s 
on s.campaign_no = c.campaign_no
set actualcost = s.cost
where c.campaign_no = 1
;
```

Where the sub query does the needful

if you simplify your data this should be easy to prove;

```
drop table if exists salarygrade,campaign,workson,staffongrade;

CREATE TABLE  `salarygrade` 
(  GRADE INT NOT NULL,
  hOURLYRATE decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);
insert into salarygrade values(1,10),(2,20);

cREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staffongrade` (
  `STAFFNO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `GRADE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINISHDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
  );

insert into staffongrade values
(1,1,'2019-01-01','2019-06-30'),(1,2,'2019-06-01','2019-12-31'),(2,1,'2019-01-01','2019-01-31');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campaign` (
  `CAMPAIGN_NO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGNSTARTDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTIMATEDCOST` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTUALCOST` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL
  );

insert into campaign values (1,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31',null,null);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workson` (
  `STAFFNO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_NO` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `WDATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `HOUR` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL
  );

insert into workson values
(1,1,'2019-01-01',1),(1,1,'2019-12-01',1),(2,1,'2019-01-01',1);

select * from campaign;
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+
| CAMPAIGN_NO | CAMPAIGNSTARTDATE | CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE | ESTIMATEDCOST | ACTUALCOST |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+
|           1 | 2019-01-01        | 2019-12-31         |          NULL |         40 |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Got to dash so I'll leave you to drop the update into a procedure.

IF staffongrade has NULL for finishdate then a bit of data cleansing is required. for simplicity I would create a temporary table to fill in gaps and change the update statement to use the projectfinishdate (if that's not known then substitute a suitable future date). This code would be inserted in your procedure prior to the update

so

```
insert into staffongrade values
(1,1,'2019-01-01',null),(1,2,'2019-07-01',null),(2,1,'2019-01-01',null);

drop temporary table if exists staffongradetemp;
create temporary table staffongradetemp like staffongrade;

insert into staffongradetemp 
select s.STAFFNO,s.GRADE,s.STARTDATE,
         case when s.FINISHDATE is not null then s.finishdate 
         else date_sub((select s1.startdate 
            from staffongrade s1 
             where s1.STAFFNO = s.STAFFNO and s1.startdate > s.STARTDATE 
             order by startdate limit 1), interval 1 day)
         end
from staffongrade s
;

select * from staffongradetemp;

+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| STAFFNO | GRADE | STARTDATE  | FINISHDATE |
+---------+-------+------------+------------+
|       1 |     1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-06-30 |
|       1 |     2 | 2019-07-01 | NULL       |
|       2 |     1 | 2019-01-01 | NULL       |
+---------+-------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which leaves all the last finshdates as null which we can trap in the update statement using coalesce

```
update  campaign c
join 
(select c.campaign_no,
         sum(hour * hourlyrate) cost
from campaign c
join workson  w on w.campaign_no = c.campaign_no
join **staffongradetemp s** on s .staffno = w.staffno and w.wdate between s.startdate and **coalesce(s.finishdate,c.CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE)**
join salarygrade g on g.grade = s.grade
where c.campaign_no = 1
group by c.campaign_no
) s 
on s.campaign_no = c.campaign_no
set actualcost = s.cost
where 1 = 1;
```

Comment: Hello, this worked after I did some tweaking, thanks for that!
Although there are instances where the `staffongrade` table has a null finish date where this doesn't work. I did some testing and believe it's due to the `join staffongrade s on s.staffno = w.staffno and w.wdate between s.startdate and s.finishdate` line. Which doesn't work if the `staffongrade` table has a `finishdate` that is null. If null, I want to determine the matching date to be after the `wdate` until the next entry's `startdate`, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So some staff have multiple grades but some of these have null as the finishdate even though a later start date may exist AND all staff who have only 1 grade will have null as the finishdate.AND the last grade always has null as a finishdate

Comment: Any NULL startdates?

Comment: No NULL startdates. Yes the last grade always has null as a finishdate, I believe it's not returning a value for cost due to this

Comment: Please see edit Code changes to update enclosed in **